# C++ list - add items

Tags: c++, list

I'm new to C++ and have a problem using list. I can't understand why i'm getting an error in the example bellow.

GameObject class is an abstract class
Player class and Bullet class inherit GameObject class

```
list<GameObject*> gameObjects = list<GameObject*>();
gameObjects.push_front(&player);
while(gameLoop)
{
    if (canShoot)
    {
        Bullet b = Bullet(player.Position.X , player.Position.Y);
        gameObjects.push_front(&b);
    }   
    for each (GameObject *obj in gameObjects)
    {
        (*obj).Update(); // get an error
    }
}
```

The error is Debug Error -Abort() Has Been Called.

Comment: Which error? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Baltasarq I'm guessing the error where he is poop9ng through a vector full of disposed objects? Probably SEGFAULTS

Comment: Why do you need `list<GameObject*> gameObjects = list<GameObject*>();` ? I mean the initialization part.

Comment: Sure, he is creating objects in the stack, instead of the heap. Hey, what's that "for each"? Anyway, if he is seeking for help, he could provide a lot more information...

Comment: `(*obj).Update()` can easily be written as `obj->Update()`

Comment: As a general improvement, use STL containers with smart pointers instead of naked pointers. Avoids memory leaks and makes the code easier to make exception-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` syntax is just wrong, and actually, more is, to loop over every element in the list make it:

```
for (GameObject *obj : gameObjects)
{
   obj->Update(); 
}
```

Or, pre C++11:

```
for(std::list<GameObject*>::iterator itr = gameObjects.begin(); itr != gameObjects.end(); ++itr)
{
  (*itr)->Update();
}
```

Also, you are creating a `Bullet` object in the scope of `if (canShoot)` and push it's address to the `std::list<GameObject*>`. By the time you reach your `foreach` the `Bullet` object will already have been destroyed and thus your pointers in the list are dangling.

Dynamically allocate your objects on the heap:

```
list<GameObject*> gameObjects;

while(gameLoop)
{
    if (canShoot)
    {
        Bullet* b = new Bullet(player.Position.X , player.Position.Y);
        gameObjects.push_front(b);
    }   
    for (GameObject* obj : gameObjects)
    {
        obj->Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :). But now the compiler is telling me:  Error C2259 'GameObject': cannot instantiate abstract class